# Stored Procedure to Update Column in TableA to TableB Value +1 For Each Change In The Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, stored-procedures, foreach

I have a TableA that has an TransID I created to keep certain records together. Once those records have been reviewed, I need to assign TableA.DocNum to TableB.DocNum value +1

TableA

| TransId | DocNum |
| --- | --- |
| 5 |  |
| 5 |  |
| 6 |  |
| 6 |  |
| 7 |  |
| 7 |  |

TableB

| DocNum |
| --- |
| 0000001 |

TableA Finished Result

| TransId | DocNum |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 0000002 |
| 5 | 0000002 |
| 6 | 0000003 |
| 6 | 0000003 |
| 7 | 0000004 |
| 7 | 0000004 |

TableB Finished Result

TableB

| DocNum |
| --- |
| 0000004 |

I have tried a loop but it didn't seem to work.

Comment: A hint: `select dense_rank() over(order by transid) from TableA`. Also, what's up with all the zeroes in 0000001. Do you say it's 0000005 o'clock?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach using dense_rank()

**Example or [dbFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7bhg3iT2)**

```
with cte as (
Select * 
      ,NewVal = format(B.Base+dense_rank() over (order by TransID),'0000000')
 from TableA A
 Cross Join ( Select Base=try_convert(int,max(DocNum)) from TableB) B
 Where A.DocNum is null
)
Update cte set DocNum=NewVal

Update TableB set DocNum = (select max(DocNum) from @TableA)

Select * from TableA
Select * from TableB
```

**Results**

```
TransID DocNum
4       0000001   -- Added for demo
5       0000002
5       0000002
6       0000003
6       0000003
7       0000004
7       0000004

DocNum
0000004
```